# Why don't all interceptors have method filtering?

Tags: struts2, interceptor

It seems that method filtering is a good feature for an interceptor, I wonder why not all interceptors have `includeMethod (excludeMethod)` properties. As mentioned only these interceptors could have filter methods :

1. TokenInterceptor
2. TokenSessionStoreInterceptor
3. DefaultWorkflowInterceptor
4. ValidationInterceptor

Comment: Do you know some existing interceptor which will benefit from extending `MethodFilterInterceptor`? BTW currently there are more interceptors extending `MethodFilterInterceptor`.

Comment: I found the list at https://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/MethodFilterInterceptor.html but it seems you are correct .  conversionError also has these methods

Comment: For example: LoggingInterceptor

Comment: Interceptors are for cross-cutting concerns, and in general, don't need method-level filtering. Things like validation make sense, for obvious reasons. A good portion of the default functionality needs to happen across all methods, no matter what.

Comment: That makes me think the method filter interceptor is obsolete.

Comment: I sometime face situations where I filter for method names and decide to run interceptor or not... So as monitored this must not be a good design  approach, am I right ?!

Comment: I also find that parameters-interceptor also can accept Method filter Since XWork 2.0.2,. as refer to https://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html